# Failed to apply plugin 'no.nils.wsdl2java'. Configuration with name 'compile' not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

when migrating to gradle 7.x getting below error

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'no.nils.wsdl2java', version: '0.12']
> Failed to apply plugin 'no.nils.wsdl2java'.
   > Configuration with name 'compile' not found.
```

Below is wsdl2java added in build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("no.nils.wsdl2java") version "0.12"
    `java-library`
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("no.nils:wsdl2java:0.12")
    }
}
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`no.nils.wsdl2java` is not compatible with Gradle 7 and is no longer maintained. See the [README](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java/blob/master/README.md) in the project. The `compile` configuration has long been deprecated and was finally removed in Gradle 7.

You can use `io.mateo.cxf-codegen` in place of `no.nils.wsdl2java`. It is a Gradle port of the Maven CXF codegen plugin.

```
plugins {
    id "io.mateo.cxf-codegen" version "2.3.0"
}
```

https://github.com/ciscoo/cxf-codegen-gradle

https://ciscoo.github.io/cxf-codegen-gradle/docs/current/user-guide/

---

Note, I am the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

if trying to use cxf with `Gradle 7.3.3` to do wsdl2java this worked for me with Kotlin script.

```kotlin
plugins {
  java
  id("io.mateo.cxf-codegen") version "1.0.1"
}

repositories {
  gradlePluginPortal()
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}
```